# Javascript adding integers as a string

Tags: javascript, html

http://unkk9a8915e1.neonz27.koding.io/genetics

Example if you add 6 and 4 with range of 1-2 you get 641 or 642 instead of 11 or 12!

```js
function calculate()
{
  var radius1 = document.getElementById("cell1Value").value;
  var radius2 = document.getElementById("cell2Value").value;
  var radiusAvrg = (radius1 + radius2) / 2;
  var childRadius = radius1 + radius2 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  console.log(childRadius);
  confirm("The child's radius is " + childRadius);
}
```

```html
<h1>ParentCell01's Radius</h1>
<input type="text" name="cell1Value" id="cell1Value" />
<br />
<h1>ParentCell02's Radius</h1>
<input type="text" name="cell2Value" id="cell2Value"/>
<br />
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate child's radius.</button>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the values to numbers:

```
var radius1 = +document.getElementById("cell1Value").value;
var radius2 = +document.getElementById("cell2Value").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your string containing int value before doing a mathematical operation like

```
var radius1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("cell1Value").value);
```

Comment: Why do you use parseInt instead of casting?

Comment: @josephcoggins, because you need to cast both values.

Comment: And if you *are* going to use `parseInt()` you really should specify a radix, especially since this applies to user-entered data.

Comment: @nnnnnn, radix is needed only for non-strict mode, you can safely skip it if you use stict mode and are not afraid of prefixes like 0x.

Answer (score 0):

Here your function should look like.

```
 function calculate()
        {
            var radius1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("cell1Value").value);
            var radius2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("cell2Value").value);
            var radiusAvrg = (radius1 + radius2) / 2;
            var childRadius = radius1 + radius2 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * radiusAvrg) + 1);
            console.log(childRadius);
            confirm("The child's radius is " + childRadius);
        }
```